# problem in understanding macro expansion rules

Tags: c, macros

Being a beginner I am having difficulty to understand the following statement

> a)If in the replacement list of a
>   function-like macro, a parameter is
>   immediately preceded or followed by a
>   ## preprocessing token, the parameter is replaced by the corresponding
>   argument's preprocessing token
>   sequence;
>
> b)For both object-like and
>   function-like macro invocations,
>   before the replacement list is
>   reexamined for more macro names to
>   replace, each instance of a ##
>   preprocessing token in the replacement
>   list (not from an argument) is deleted
>   and the preceding preprocessing token
>   is concatenated with the following
>   preprocessing token

would you please like to help me to comprehend the above statement with some simple example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Macro**

```
#define MAKE_EVENT_HANDLER(x)  void On##x(void) {
```

---

**Usage**

```
MAKE_EVENT_HANDLER(MouseClick)
   /* Do stuff */
} // End of function
```

---

**How it Expands**

```
void OnMouseClick(void) { /* Do stuff */ }
```

Comment: Don't forget part b. Also: C, not C++. +1 for good clarity though.

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I wrote a couple of articles covering the preprocessor. They contain both technical stuff as well as the folklore. Part 2 covers the # and ## operators.

Part 1: [Basics of using the preprocessor](https://www.iar.com/knowledge/learn/programming/basics-of-using-the-preprocessor/)

Part 2: [Advanced preprocessor tips and tricks](https://www.iar.com/knowledge/learn/programming/advanced-preprocessor-tips-and-tricks/)

Comment: part 2 is helpful I always forget these rules

Answer (score 0):

wikipedia has a nice illustration -> [token pasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation)

Comment: YEAP...but what does following statement means "Only function-like parameters can be pasted in a macro, and the parameters are not parsed for macro replacement first, so the following somewhat non-intuitive behavior occurs:"

Comment: i am not sure what is meant by "function-like parameters". there is no use in using ## if neither operand is a parameter of the function macro.
the parameters are substituted once,  then ## will be processed before attempting substitution again. (unlike our expectation that substitution occurs recursively until exhausted)